# HTML/JS directory disappears on production server

Tags: angularjs, html, tomcat, jenkins, jhipster

So, I have a full-stack web application generated with `JHipster`, I have recently needed to change the name of one of the entities in the webapp area and the template/js files because it was clashing (had the term api in it)

Now it all works just fine in local, but when uploading the application to jenkins for production it just won't want to find the new files

I have tried:

- Hard reload / Ctrl + Shift + Del / and opening in a different browser
- Erasing the target folder.
- Wiping the whole workspace from jenkins.
- I created a new item in jenkins.
- Changing the href manually in the developer tools

All unsuccesful and result in the same error message

The most annoying thing is that it works like a charm when deploying in local, with both dev and prod profiles.

This is the error message I get on the console, obviously it never reaches the back-end so remote debugging was useless for this:

```
GET [long url here]/app/entities/trade-drug-capi/trade-drug-capis.html?cacheBuster=1488389348167 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Which jhipster version? angular 1 or 2? Have you tried building with prod profile locally and then run 'java !jar target/*.war'

Comment: Hi @GaëlMarziou, It's JHipster 3.0.0 according to the first line of the gulpfile, Angular 1.5,  and no, I haven't tried that option, however I ended up erasing everything new yesterday and starting from scrap, if I hit the same error I will try this option and pick the thread up again.  Thanks!